# I do not know the meaning of the error that is being displayed in the console

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was trying to make a website on the meteor platform. Everything was going well but now I am encountering these errors which are mentioned below:

```
<strong>Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.<br/>
Exception from Tracker recompute function:<br/>
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null<br/>
    at builtins.js:237<br/>
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:589)<br/>
    at Object.eachView.stopHandle.ObserveSequence.observe.changedAt (builtins.js:229)<br/>
    at observe_sequence.js:274<br/>
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:113)<br/>
    at diffArray (observe_sequence.js:260)<br/>
    at observe_sequence.js:108<br/>
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:589)<br/>
    at observe_sequence.js:82<br/>
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)<br/></strong>
```

I do not know from where these errors are coming. can any one help me regarding this. Apologies for any mistake in posting the question.

Comment: you are passing a null where it expects a false value or array

Comment: Looks like you are passing something that is not an array, cursor or falsy value to `each`.... Without seeing the code it'll be quite difficult to provide any more info above what is already stated in the error message...

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: You may need to add more of your code se we could help you

Comment: I understood but I am not able to get which {{#each}} function in my code is causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% chances that you are passing an object to an #each in your template.

If you cannot identify easily that object because you have multiple #each, you can try to log the passed objects. With the following helper :

```
UI.registerHelper( 'log', ( content ) => {
    return console.log( content );
} );
```

(and keep it, it's usefull)

Just log your elements that way :

```
{{log target}}
{{#each target}}
    ...
```

One of your targets is going to be null, an object or whatever, but not an array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Template.registerHelper(...) ;)